# Bases and inner products

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I am not quite sure what this question is asking for:

> Given $f(\vec{x})=x^2+xy+y^2+yz+z^2+xz$, find a basis for the corresponding inner product on $\mathbb R^3$.

(I was told that there is an obvious orthogonal basis -- obtainable by inspection)

I don't even know what "corresponding inner product" means...

Thanks.

Comment: A positive-definite quadratic form is essentially an inner product. To get an explicit expression for the symmetric bilinear form, look up the polarisation formula.

Comment: Thanks, @ZhenLin, but I still don't quite understand this, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @ZhenLin: What does it mean to find a basis for an inner product?

Comment: The problem is a bit vague, but note $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T A \vec{x}$ where $A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1  & 1/2 & 1/2\\1/2  & 1 & 1/2\\1/2  & 1/2 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$. Given positive semidefinite matrix $B$, one can define an inner product: $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle_B = \vec{x}^T B \vec{y}$. See the connection?

Comment: I think "find a basis for an inner product" means "find a basis B for the vector space such that B is orthonormal with respect to the inner product."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: THanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much to give away. The matrix being introduced is
$$ M \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \frac{1}{2}  & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}  & 1  
\end{array} 
  \right)  ,
  $$

which is symmetric, and an orthogonal basis is indeed pretty easy to find. If required, one may then normalize to get an orthonormal basis.  If we take a column vector $x$ and its transpose $x^T,$ then the value of the quadratic form at the point $x$ is just
$$ f(x) = x^T \; M \; x.  $$
The inner product of two vectors $x,y$ is given by
$$  \langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left(f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y)\right) = x^T M y = y^T M x$$ which is one way to write polarization.

Here is something not mentioned. If you take all three entries in $\vec{x}$ to be integers, the result $f(\vec{x})$ is a nonnegative integer. Not all positive integers show up, though. A number $n \geq 0$ has a "representation" $n=f(x)$ if and only if $n$ is not of the form $4^k (16 m + 14).$ Go figure.

Comment: Thanks, Will. Is the "basis" simply the columns of $M$? I don't know what the definition of a basis of an inner product is... Also, very interesting last point!

Comment: In any case, the columns of M are not the basis of anything. From what you asked, find an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of M... What course is this for? The type of answer for a linear algebra course (everything over the real numbers) is rather different from the best reply for a number theory course.

Comment: It is for linear algebra.

Comment: Though the $x,y,z$ may or may not be real.

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: It is not from a textbook, unfortunately, it's just a set question from class.